# Proof that subspace $U$ of a finite dim vector space $V$ is also finite dim and $\dim(U)\leq\dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

In my class lecture there was a longer proof of this than what I thought, so I want to check with you guys what flaws my argument has:

Since $V$ is a finite-dimensional VS, *by definition*, it has a finite unordered basis $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_m\}$ such that $V=\text{span}(S)$. Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$, any $u\in U$ also lies in $V=\text{span}(S)$. So $u=\sum_i a^is_i$.

Thus any arbitrary vector in $U$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $S$. More generally it may be that coefficients corresponding to a subset of vectors in $S$ are zero in expressions for all vectors in $U$ (e.g. $a^1$ is always zero, so that subset would be $\{s_1\}$). In that case a subset of $S$ would span $U$.

So either $S$ or a subset of it (both independent) span $U$, are finite and therefore form a finite unordered basis of $U$.

This completes the argument, but is there any flaw in it?

Comment: There is not necessarily a subset of $S$ that spans $U$, consider e.g. $V=\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ and $U=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ where $S$ is the standard basis. However it is always possible to choose a basis such that a subset of it spans $U$

Comment: If $\{u_1, \cdots, u_n\}$ are linearly independent in $U$ then they are linearly independent in $V$.

Comment: @leoli1: Thanks! That clarified it for me. So I'll have to construct a basis for $U$ rather than choosing from an existing basis for $V$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it is incorrect. Only *some* subspaces are generated by subsets of a basis, precisely $2^n$ of them.

For instance, assuming $n\ge2$, $\operatorname{span}\{v_1+v_2\}$ is not generated by a subset of $S$: indeed, it has dimension $1$ and no vector of $S$ belongs in it.

The proof is done by recursively constructing new vectors in $U$, ensuring to get a linearly independent set.

If $U=\{0\}$, then there is nothing to prove. Otherwise there exists $u_1\in U$, $u_1\notin U_0=\{0\}$.

Suppose we have built the linearly independent subset $\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ of $U$ and that $U_k=\operatorname{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}\ne U$. Then there is $u_{k+1}\in U$, $u_{k+1}\notin U_k$ and the set
$$
\{u_1,\dots,u_k,u_{k+1}\}
$$
is easily seen to be linearly independent. Since the process cannot go beyond $n=\dim V$, because no linearly independent set in $V$ can have more than $n$ elements, we see that at some stage $k$ we must have $U_k=U$. Then $k=\dim U\le \dim V$.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty stupid of me. I did have doubt about precisely that step "any arbitrary vector in $U$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $S$". I guess it's always worthwhile to verify doubtful statements through simple examples like what @leoli1 pointed out in a comment.